# Is there any equivalent for Jupiter for Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, power-management, jupiter

I am looking for a software like Jupiter for my Kubuntu 12.04 to reduce my battery usage.
I want to know, Is there any equivalent for Jupiter for Kubuntu ? or how can i run Jupiter on Kubuntu?

Thanks.

Comment: I have installed it on Kubuntu and work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have installed it on Kubuntu 12.04 and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Jupiter is an application for Linux so it should work on Kubuntu.

Comment: Does it work well on Kubuntu as well as in Ubuntu or Gnome?

Comment: I don't use it so I don't know.